# Xamarin Forms Sqlite create task

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, task

I use an SQLite at my xamarin project. I have a class and when I want to retrieve records I use the
following tasks like

```
public Task<List<Movies_RecDef>> GetMovies_RecDefs_ByID(int ID)
        {
            string sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM [Movies_RecDef] where [ID]  =  " + ID;
            return _database.QueryAsync<Movies_RecDef>(sqlStr);
        }
```

I want to create a task to return the number of records in the table or the name of a field but I confused the variables that I use.

Comment: You want to return the number of records? not clear your last sentence

Comment: `select count(*) ...` to get the number of records

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a task to return the number of records in the table or the name of a field but I confused the variables that I use.

This is my class Managers:

```
public class Managers
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I create SQLiteHelper class to get some data from Sqlite database.

```
public  class SQLiteHelper
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection db;
    public SQLiteHelper(string dbPath)
    {
        db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);        
        db.CreateTableAsync<Managers>().Wait();
    }

    //Insert and Update new record  
    public Task<int> SaveItemAsync(Managers person)
    {
        if (person.ID != null)
        {
            return db.UpdateAsync(person);
        }
        else
        {
            return db.InsertAsync(person);
        }
    }

    //Delete  
    public Task<int> DeleteItemAsync(Managers person)
    {
        return db.DeleteAsync(person);
    }

    //Read All Items  
    public Task<List<Managers>> GetItemsAsync()
    {
        return db.Table<Managers>().ToListAsync();
    }
 
    //Read Item  
    public Task<Managers> GetItemAsync(int personId)
    {
        return db.Table<Managers>().Where(i => i.ID == personId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

Now, you can get Records count or get any one record by using Id parameter.

```
   SQLiteHelper db;
 private async void btnget_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Managers m = await db.GetItemAsync(1);
    }
   
    private async void btngetcount_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Managers> datas = await db.GetItemsAsync();
        int count = datas.Count;
    }
```